# Catchable fatal error: cannot be converted to string?

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, fatal-error

I can't solve the problem of

`"Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string."`

I have 3 tables: photos (photo_id, photo_filename, photo_caption), tags(tag_id, tag_title)
where tag_title is unique, and photos_tags (photo_id, tag_id).

The user can add tags that describe the photo (he can insert as many tags as he want, separate them with commas). For every tag I want to check if it already exists so that can I avoid duplication in table photos_tags. It works for table photos and tags, but I can't fill the table photos_tags.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$tags = $tag_title;
$e = explode(',', $tags);

foreach($e as $value) //for every tag
{
    $q_photo_id = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT photo_id FROM photos WHERE 
    (photo_filename ='$photo_filename' AND photo_caption = '$photo_caption')");
    $photo_id = mysqli_fetch_array($q_photo_id);
    $sql4 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (tag_title) VALUES ('$value')");

    if (mysqli_insert_id($con)) {

        $q_tag_id = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE ('tag_title' = '$value')");
        $tag_id = mysqli_fetch_array($q_tag_id);
    } 
    else { //if the tag already exist

        $q_tag_id = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE ('tag_title' = '$value')");
        $tag_id = mysqli_fetch_array($q_tag_id);
    }
 // insert into photos_tags
     $sql6 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO photos_tags (photo_id, tag_id) VALUES ('$photo_id', '$tag_id')");

    }
}
```

Comment: In which line you are getting this error

Comment: You should use $photo_id instead of $q_photo_id in the last query!

Comment: @Darhazer It wouldn't cause this error

Comment: Ops, I forgot to change that, I do have $photo_id and $tag_id in the last query, but it still doesn't work. 
I am getting an error in this last query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to see why debugging this is a problem. You should insert strings, or something that could be cast into strings. Here you are using `$q_photo_id` and `$q_tag_id` both of which are `mysqli_result` objects. They can't be cast into strings, and PHP rightfully complains about the same. You should use `$photo_id[0]` and `$tag[0]` instead

Comment: Thank you, there is no error anymore but the table photos_tags it's still empty. :/

Comment: That's unfortunate. Try investigating why the problem occurred with a proper debugging engine like xdebug. If it is difficult to setup, you may want to check the return value of the last query. Also, inspect the complete query that is being executed (using echo or die). Personally, I prefer PDO over mysqli